# What can be said about collection of the unprovable formulas?

Tags: logic, model-theory

From Godel's completeness theorem and incompleteness theorem, we can deduce that given certain nonlogical axioms, some unprovable formulas are true in some models of the axioms and false in others.

Let's consider the collection of such formulas, then what can we say about it? Is there any theory about that? Could you please point out any reference material on that? Any help is welcomed!

Comment: First of all , statements that can be disproven, are also unprovable (Of course we must assume that the theory is consistent , otherwise everything is provable). What you probably mean are statements that can neither be proven nor disproven. Unfortunately, such statements can in general not be detected and be seperated from the provable or disprovable ones. We can only collect cases for which we can do that.

Comment: For a very important example, study the Goodstein sequences. That they all terminate cannot be proven within the peano axioms, but the set theory is able to prove that.

Comment: @Peter Statements under consideration are surely those can neither be proven nor disproven, otherwise they would always be false in all the models of the axioms. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Since both propositional calculus (as proved first by Post) and first-order logic (as proved first by Goedel) are both complete and sound, I've removed some tags from this question.

Answer (score 4):

Theorem 5.2 in [this paper](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ecristian/aam.pdf) by Calude and Jürgensen (2005), with my editing for clarity, states

> Consider a consistent, sound, finitely-specified theory strong enough
> to formalize arithmetic. The probability that a true sentence of
> length $n$ is provable in the theory tends to zero when $n$ tends to
> infinity, while the probability that a sentence of length $n$ is true exceeds a positive quantity which is independent of $n$.

Comment: Related [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288933/50073) that hasn't gotten an answer.